# Merge custom content in Composables

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 custom components in Jetpack Compose:

```
@Composable
fun IconText(modifier: Modifier, icon: Int, text: String) {/**/}
```

and a grid where it is currently hardcoded:

```
@Composable
fun VerticalGrid( //fun <T> VerticalGrid(
    data: List<Pair<Resource, Int>>, //List<T>,
    columnCount: Int,
    itemContent: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val size = data.size
    val rows = if (size == 0) 0 else 1 + (size - 1) / columnCount


    for (rowIndex in 0..rows) {
        val itemIndex = rowIndex * columnCount

        Row {
            val end = min(itemIndex + columnCount, size)
            for (index in itemIndex until end) {
                IconText(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), data[index].first.image, data[index].second.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the grid more customisable and change `IconText` to the custom `itemContent`?

Comment: This grid is already used inside `LazyVerticalGrid`, so it's not necessary to commend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing parameters to content lambda

```
@Composable
fun IconText(modifier: Modifier, icon: Int, text: String) {/**/
}

@Composable
fun VerticalGrid( //fun <T> VerticalGrid(
    data: List<Pair<Resource, Int>>, //List<T>,
    columnCount: Int,
    itemContent: @Composable (Modifier, Int, String) -> Unit
) {
    val size = data.size
    val rows = if (size == 0) 0 else 1 + (size - 1) / columnCount


    for (rowIndex in 0..rows) {
        val itemIndex = rowIndex * columnCount

        Row {
            val end = min(itemIndex + columnCount, size)
            for (index in itemIndex until end) {
                itemContent(
                    Modifier.weight(1f),
                    data[index].first.image,
                    data[index].second.toString()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
VerticalGrid(data = listOf(), columnCount = 10) { modifier, icon, text ->
    IconText(modifier, icon, text)
}
```

Or

```
  VerticalGrid(data = listOf(), columnCount = 10) { modifier, icon, text ->
        Tex(modifier, text)
    }
```

Or

```
  VerticalGrid(data = listOf(), columnCount = 10) { modifier, icon, text ->
        IconText(modifier, icon, text)
        Tex(modifier, text)
    }
```

With last one you need to consider how you set Modifier. Since it's a Row under the hood. If first Composable covers whole space second one won't be visible

With generic function

```
@Composable
fun <T> VerticalGrid(
    data: List<T>,
    columnCount: Int,
    itemContent: @Composable (Modifier, T) -> Unit
) {
    val size = data.size
    val rows = if (size == 0) 0 else 1 + (size - 1) / columnCount


    for (rowIndex in 0..rows) {
        val itemIndex = rowIndex * columnCount

        Row {
            val end = min(itemIndex + columnCount, size)
            for (index in itemIndex until end) {
                itemContent(Modifier.weight(1f), data[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
val list: List<Pair<Resource, Int>> = listOf(
    Pair(Resource(1), 1)
)

VerticalGrid(
    data = list,
    columnCount = 10
) { modifier: Modifier, pair: Pair<Resource, Int> ->

    IconText(
        modifier = modifier,
        icon = pair.first.image,
        text = pair.second.toString()
    )
}
```

Comment: It's a step forward, but how can I use any custom component here? Like next time I want to use `Text` or `Image` instead of `IconText`?

Comment: Change  IconText inside lambda to Text in usage section. It's now like a default composable but returns modifier, icon and text that is set internally inside implementation

Comment: `itemContent: @Composable (Modifier, Int, String)` should be changed too?

Comment: no. It's internal implementation. You consider this as Box for instance. You only change what you put inside Box. And Box returns BoxScope we return modifier, icon and text

Comment: Thanks. I see, I need to keep common parameters in `itemContent: @Composable (Modifier, Int, String)`, can't make them a wildcard. Also I suppose, it's possible to cut the data type `data: List<Pair<Resource, Int>>`

Comment: You can play with your data type any way that permits conversion or type casting. You can also create a RowScope as receiver if you wish to be able to get Modifiers or properties from Row such as `itemContent: @Composable RowScope.(Modifier, Int, String) -> Unit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246993/discussion-between-thracian-and-psijic).

Comment: @Psijic check updated answer